# Why does my website have referrals from http://1.1.1.3/fcgi/websAuth?

Tags: google-analytics, referrer

I just got an question from my Google Analytics expert that is identifying a lot of referrals from this IP

http://1.1.1.3/fcgi/websAuth

http://1.1.1.3/fcgi/websVlanAuth

[image: referral]

i check all my server settings, i have anothers site in this server and i dont have this issue, also i check for virus and everything, but not idea why im having this referrals , also this is tracked as mobile traffic, i checked the ip with ip trace and it said is from google Australia

any clue of this and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The referrer header sent with a HTTP request is completely unreliable. In your case, `http://1.1.1.3/fcgi/websAuth` might be a referring page on a private network, a deliberately spoofed referrer, or set by a misconfigured or buggy proxy server. There's probably nothing you can do about that.

Another big problem is referrer spam used to advertise certain websites. I typically create a segment that excludes all referrers that look fishy.